# Does dominant morphism of integral schemes is injective on sheaves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a dominant morphism of integral schemes. Is it true that it is equivalent to the fact that  $\mathcal O_Y \to f_* \mathcal O_X$ is injective? Or does one imply another? It's quite easy that they are equivalent in the case of affine morphism, but I can't understand are they equivalent in the general case?

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\Ohol}{{\mathcal O}}$
$\newcommand{\sheaf}[1]{{\mathcal #1}}$
$\newcommand{\ideal}[1]{{\mathfrak #1}}$
$\newcommand{\spec}[1]{{{\mathrm{spec}}(#1)}}$
$\newcommand{\PSP}{{\mathbb P}}$

When $f:X \to Y$ is in addition quasicompact and separated then we have an
exact sequence of quasi-coherent sheafs
$$0 \to \sheaf{I} \to \Ohol_Y \to f_*\Ohol_X$$
and the scheme theoretic image of $f$, call it $Z$, is $V(\sheaf{I})$. It is
$Z= \overline{f(X)}$. So if $\Ohol_Y \to f_* \Ohol_X$ is injective then $\sheaf{I} = 0$ and $f$ is dominant. Otherway, if $V(\sheaf{I}) = Y$ then $\sheaf{I}$ must be zero as $Y$ is integral.

In fact for $X,Y$ integral schemes one does not need assumptions on $f$.
For any scheme $X$ and  $s \in \Ohol_X(X)$ call $X_s = \{x \in X \mid s_x \notin \ideal{m}_x\}$ 
where $\ideal{m}_x$ is the maximal ideal of $\Ohol_{X,x}$ and $s_x$ is the image of $s$ under the canonical map $\Ohol_X(X) \to \Ohol_{X,x}$.

Now assume first that $Y=\spec{A}$ affine. Then we have $f^{-1}(Y_a) = X_{\phi(a)}$ where $a \in A$ and 
$$\phi=f^\sharp:\Ohol_Y(Y) \to (f_*\Ohol_X)(Y) = \Ohol_X(X).$$

Now we have the equivalences
$f:X \to Y$ dominant. $\Leftrightarrow$ $f^{-1}(D(a)) \neq \emptyset$ for all $a \in A$ with $a \neq 0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $X_{\phi(a)} \neq \emptyset$
$\Leftrightarrow$ $\phi(a) \neq 0$ in $\Ohol_X(X)$.

The last equivalence can easily be seen by considering affine open subsets of $X$. Let $X_s$ with $s \in \Ohol_X(X)$ be given, then for all $U=\spec{B} \subseteq X$ we have $X_s \cap U = U_t$ where $t$ is the image of $s$ in $B$. Now if $X_s = \emptyset$ we have $U_t = \emptyset$ and as $B$ is integral $t$ is zero, so considering all $U$ also $s$ is zero. On the other hand if $s$ is zero then obviously $X_s = \emptyset$.

Now for the general case where $Y$ needs not be affine we have the implications:

$f:X \to Y$ dominant $\Leftrightarrow$ $f:f^{-1}(V) \to V$ dominant for all $V \subseteq Y$ affine. $\Leftrightarrow$ $\Ohol_Y(V) \to \Ohol_X(f^{-1}(V))$ injective for all $V \subseteq Y$ affine. $\Leftrightarrow$ $\Ohol_Y \to f_*\Ohol_X$ injective.

It may be noted that the whole proof above for the integral case follows quite closely the lines of the proof for $X,Y$ affine with $X_s$ taking the place of the $D(s)$ in the affine case.

Comment: Why do we need $f$ to be separated?

Comment: It is necessary so that $f_* {\mathcal O}_X$ is a quasicoherent ${\mathcal O}_Y$-module. In fact $f$ quasi-separated would be enough, that means $\Delta:X \to X \times_Y X$ is quasicompact. Also $f$ quasi-compact and $X$ noetherian would be sufficient.

Comment: According to http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01R5 quasicompactness of $f$ implies $ \mathcal I$ is quasicoherent and we don't need that $f_* \mathcal O_X$ is quasicoherent, if I understood everything wright.

Comment: Also I'm interested in example of dominant morphism such that $\mathcal O_Y \to f_* \mathcal O_X$ is not injective. Do you know anyone?

Comment: @6574765467 For $X,Y$ integral there is no such example. I extended my answer giving a proof for this fact.